# Unable to update Nexus 7 2012 32gb from 4.2.1 to 4.3

Tags: updates

I bought my google Nexus 7 2012 32gb wifi only today. It has stock 4.2.1 and it is showing that an update to 4.3 is available but whenever i go there it always states that waiting to download-172.1MB.

I tried to restart it and see if it picks up the download but no use, its in the same way. Please can any one help me, i dont want to Root it or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check the WiFi connection you connected it to if it's working properly.

Go to settings>Apps>All>Google Services framework
and clear the data. Restart your Nexus 7 and see if the update downloads without hitch.

Comment: did that its the same.... :( thank you though

Comment: it happens to offer an option for search for updates and then after the moment it finds an update it immediately goes to the waiting for download.